# while converting number 0.001 to BN.js instance, error: Value must be an integer, hex string, BN or BigNumber instance

Tags: web3js, ether, ethereumjs, bignumber

I want to transfer 0.001 token and I cannot use `web3.utils.toWei(0.001)` as the smart contract has 12 decimal instead of 18 decimal. How can I correct it ?

```
  var decimals = 12;
  var amount = web3.utils.toBN(web3.utils.toHex(0.001)); <--- Getting error here
  let value = amount.mul(web3.utils.toBN(10).pow(decimals));
```

The error is:

```
[number-to-bn] while converting number 0.001 to BN.js instance, error: invalid number value. Value must be an integer, hex string, BN or BigNumber instance. Note, decimals are not supported. Given value: "0.001"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

BN will not accept decimal point numbers. You can do as follows:

```
var decimals = 12;
var value = (0.001*(10**decimals)).toString();
var amount = web3.utils.toBN(value);
```

Hope this helps